# URLByResolvingBookmarkData extremely slow... solution?

Tags: objective-c, alias, nsurl, bookmarks

I have a project-like application and have a need to keep track of a few thousand resource files. Each file on the disk is represented my a "MyElement" object in my app. When I use a path to keep track of the file's location, the performance is very good... a project file with references to 4,000 files opens in about 1.5 seconds.

However, if I use bookmarks, while I gain a lot (files can move without breaking my reference to them), the performance is terrible.

Opening the same project where I have to use URLByResolvingBookmarkData to get a path to a file, it takes about 25 seconds.

Profiling the app does show that the time is spent deep in URLByResolvingBookmarkData... mostly in an OS function called volumePropertyProviderPrepareValues.

I have moved to using bookmarks, but caching the path too. However, when I open the project, it takes a long time to go over each bookmark and verify that my cached path is still current.

Is there any way to improve the performance of bookmarks in this situation?

They were created with:

```
NSData*  bookmarkData = [fileURL bookmarkDataWithOptions:NSURLBookmarkCreationMinimalBookmark includingResourceValuesForKeys:nil relativeToURL:nil error:&inError];
```

Comment: same issue for me, very slow to create and retrieve a bookmark